# UnicodeEncodeError in Python with pymysql for .fetchall()

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, pymysql

I'm trying to make a script to display my data base, are 8 columns and all are courted with utf8_unicode_ci.

This is the script:

```
import sys

import pymysql
conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', port=3306, user='root', passwd='root', db='rfid')

cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute("SELECT * FROM cnf1")

for r in cur.fetchall():
   print(r)

cur.close()
conn.close()
```

But when running the script, the console throws me the following error:

```
(1, 'camilo', 'camilo', 'camilo', 'camilo', 'camilo', 'camilo', 'camilo')
(2, 'Juan', 'Perez', 'Sanchez', '112223330', 'Las Almendras 111', 'juan.perez@correo.com', '12AAA')
(3, 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a')
(4, 'camilo1', 'camilo1', 'camilo1', 'camilo1', 'camilo1', 'camilo1', 'camilo1')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/camilonunezfernandez/Desktop/prueba2.py", line 11, in <module>
(5, 'camilo1', 'camilo1', 'camilo1', 'camilo1', 'camilo1', 'camilo1', 'camilo1')
(6, 'camilo1', 'camilo1', 'camilo1', 'camilo1', 'camilo1', 'camilo1', 'camilo1')
    print(r)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xf1' in position 5: ordinal not in range(128)
[Finished in 0.4s with exit code 1]
[cmd: ['python3', '-u', '/Users/camilonunezfernandez/Desktop/prueba2.py']]
[dir: /Users/camilonunezfernandez/Desktop]
[path: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]
```

I'm using version 3.4 of Python, which runs the 'pymysql' library to connect to my MySQL database.

They know that this error could be happening?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass charset argument

```
conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', port=3306, user='root', passwd='root', db='rfid', charset='utf8')
```